# google form scripts uncheck email

Tags: google-apps-script

write a google app script script. The situation is that the form is submitted. First, it will check whether the email address of the person who filled it already exists in the previously submitted response. If yes, the form will no longer accept forms submitted by this email address. If the filler's email address is new, it will be added to the emailList and the form will continue to be accepted. In addition, if the number of responses has reached the limit (the limit here is a full hundred), the form will also stop accepting new responses.
When the script is running, it seems that the email check cannot be executed, what is the problem?

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var emailList = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    var response = responses[i];
    var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
    
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      
      // If email address question, check for uniqueness
      if (itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() === "Email Address") {
        if (emailList.indexOf(itemResponse.getResponse()) !== -1) {
          form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
          throw new Error("This email has already been used to submit the form.");
        }
        emailList.push(itemResponse.getResponse());
      }
    }
  }
  
  // If max response limit is reached
  if (responses.length >= 100) {  // change 100 to desired max responses
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
    throw new Error("This form has reached its maximum response limit.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, about `When the script is running, it seems that the email check cannot be executed`, when I saw your script, it seems that all responses are checked. By this, when the same `Email Address` is existing before, `emailList.indexOf(itemResponse.getResponse()) !== -1` is true. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. How about this?

Comment: And also, in your script, when multiple users use the Google Form, when `form.setAcceptingResponses(false)` is run, all users cannot access the Google Form. Please be careful about this. For example, is this your 2nd issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just learned google script, because I have a problem to deal with at work, so I try to use google form and google script to solve the work problem, I know from your profile that you are Japanese, very good at google script, I am from Taiwan, I hope I can learn from you, if you don’t mind, I will continue to learn from you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Mr. Tanaike, can I ask you a few ideas? First, I want to execute the Google script when the form is submitted. I should use a trigger program. Can several trigger programs be executed at the same time? Next, the script is in the Google form Are there any major differences with Google Sheets?